# Is this possible with jquery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Currently I have made this

http://exige-media.com/api/

But what I want is if you post the form [this page](http://exige-media.com/api/index3.php) is loaded.

But when you click the 3rd tab which is ranked it should show the ranked data

So if tab = ranked show that data with the data inputted by the form on the main index

I've tried several things like checking PHP_SELF but I have so far not yet found a solution to my problem hopefully you guys can help me

Greetings

Edit so i have a php page with if $page = home and if $page = ranked what i want is if in this case tab 3 is clicked which is ranked i want to return the data under if $page == ranked from the submitted form

Comment: i really dont understand, whats your problem afterall? your form is'nt getting posted or the posted values are not getting displayed in the ranked tab? can you show me your code of the posted page?

Answer (score 2):

After you get a successful form post, you need to have a PHP redirect using

`header('Location: http://exige-media.com/api/index3.php');`

And for the 3rd tab to be activated,plug this js

`$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
});`

+1 for doing something with LOL

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use AJAX to get this data:

```
$('#tabs a[href="#ranked"]').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "script_with_ranks.php",
        type: "post",
        data: optional_values,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            $("#tabs-3").html('Submitted successfully');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#tabs-3").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

Where #tab-3 is last tab content.

Comment: ok and if it succeeded does it show the data echod back aswell?

Comment: You can return pure HTML or JSON to parse on client side (better solution).
For example JSON:
http://pl1.php.net/json_encode